# AppActivate to return to excel

Tags: vba, excel

I'm writing a code to download a file from a website, but I must use Chrome for it.
I used the shell command to open Google Chrome in the desired URL and right after the shell command I tried to use the AppActivate command but it is not working.

The command is as follow

```
Sub DL(URL as string)

    Shell ("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe -url URL")
    AppActivate ("MicroSoft Excel - SIEVE")

End Sub
```

SIEVE is the name of my workbook. I've tried using only MicroSoft Excel, Excel and other combinantions, but only with MicroSoft Excel and Microsoft Excel - SIEVE I didn't get an error message.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need to include the name of your workbook.

Try this:

```
Sub DL(URL As String)

Shell ("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe -url URL")
AppActivate "MicroSoft Excel"

End Sub
```

If you have multiple workbooks open and the wrong workbook is brought to view, you could always insert this before the `AppActivate`:

```
Workbooks("SIEVE").Activate
```

---

**Edit**

The reason `AppActivate` doesn't appear to be working is because it works too soon. The code executes before Chrome has had a chance to fully open, so Chrome is activated *after* `AppActivate` occurs. The best option I see that you have is to use [**`Application.Wait()`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822851.aspx) and wait until Chrome is loaded. Something like this:

```
Sub DL(URL As String)
    Shell ("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe -url URL")

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10")) '<~~ Waits ten seconds.

    AppActivate "MicroSoft Excel"
End Sub
```

Comment: Strange as it seems, it just won't work.
Nothing changes.
Do you know a way to close chrome?

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
On Error Resume Next
**AppActivate Application.Caption**
On Error GoTo 0
```